# String connection para aceder a sql remotamente

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho uma base de dados SQL SERVER num desktop e estou a fazer um programa noutro pc que irá aceder a essa base de dados. Queria saber como monto a minha string connection para aceder à base de dados remotamente.

Já permiti que o sql permitisse ligações remotas.

Tenho assim:
Data Source = ip_do_pc_com_base_dados, 1433, Initial Catalog = nomeBaseDados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diogo, eu acho que é isso que você procura:

```
Data Source=10.0.0.1;User ID=seu_usuario;Initial Catalog=seu_banco;pwd=sua_senha
```

- Data Source = IP do seu servidor que esta instalado o SQL Server
- User ID = Usuário que você se conecta no SQL Server
- Initial Catalog = Nome do Banco de Dados que você ira se conectar
- pwd = Senha do usuário

Veja também:

[como configurar conexão remota no sql server 2008 express?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/af1edab7-685d-4139-a20b-5395d17b7bce/como-configurar-conexo-remota-no-sql-server-2008-express?forum=vscsharppt)

[The Connection Strings Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Não consegui na mesma, será por ter no sql server windows authentication em vez de SQL Server authentication @FabioIn?

Comment: @Diego-Souza, não sei, mas dentro do site "The Connection Strings Reference" tem todos os tipos de conexões possíveis e imaginárias.